# conditional based on time

Tags: expressionengine

Is it possible to trigger a conditional in EE via the server time?

```
{if servertime == 'midnight to 13:00'}
      do this
{if:else}
      do something else
{/if}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you can use the `{current_time}` global variable for basic conditionals. To use your example, here's how we'd check that the time's between midnight and 13:00:

```
{if
    '{current_time format="%H%i"}' >= '0000' AND
    '{current_time format="%H%i"}' <= '1300'
}
    It's between 00:00 and 13:00
{if:else}
    It isn't.
{/if}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're not opposed to using a little php in your template the user guide has a basic example to get you going: http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#start-on

There's also this plugin http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cc-time-difference which may come in handy.

Answer (score 3):

Just to reiterate what Jean said - if you are doing something like this, you need to make sure your DST (Day Light Saving) is appropriately configured.

If you're not using FocusLab Config - just drop the following into your config.php (in system/expressionengine/config/)

```
 $config['daylight_savings'] = ((bool) date('I')) ? 'y' : 'n';
```

That'll sort it for you dynamically.

Comment: Sorry i don't quite understand this. Does this automate the DST Setting of EE?

Comment: Yes - this sets it automatically for you which means you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to watch your DST setup too. One way around this will be to use FocusLab's Master Config which fixes it so DST is handled automatically.